# Attribute Contains Selector * alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, onchange

NOTE: using jQuery 1.3.2 (Yep I'm upgrading but still need to be at 1.3.2 for this)

Looking for a better way to implement this

HTML Element (This is coming from a custom PHP framework and is very cumbersome to make changes to):

```
<select id="car[0][car_id]" name="car[0][car_id]">
    ... 100+ options
</select>
```

I can add another drop down dynamically which looks like this:

```
<select id="car[1][car_id]" name="car[1][car_id]">
    ... 100+ options
</select>
```

and

```
<select id="car[2][car_id]" name="car[2][car_id]">
    ... 100+ options
</select>
```

Now I'm iterating through them like this:

```
function showCarinfo() {
    for ( var car_number = 0; $("#car\\["+car_number+"\\]\\[car_id\\]").length > 0; car_number++ ) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

on change selection:

```
$("input[name*=car_id]").change(function(){
    // display info for each car selected from each drop down select menu
    showCarinfo(); 
});
```

Is there a better way to implement the on change and iterating methods? I am using the 'Attribute Contains Selector' ( http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/ ) but looks like it's causing a big performance issue with the on change event.

UPDATE:

I've replaced the * with $ to search the last part and this (I think) does help with performance a little but still looking if this is the best solution

```
$("input[name$=car_id]").change(function(){
    // display info for each car selected from each drop down select menu
    showCarinfo(); 
});
```

Comment: Which browsers are you supporting? Do you still support IE7 and lower?

Comment: FYI, the `*=` is not the *all-selector*. It's the [*attribute-contains*](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector. But the initial selection doesn't change the performance of the actual event when it occurs.

Comment: Technically, your `id`s [are invalid](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/types.html#type-name).  *"ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")."*  Brackets in your `id`s *might* work, but you're breaking spec; future browsers might not continue working with your code.

Comment: @josh3736 Thanks for the heads up, didn't even think about that. Looking at the HTML5 spec ( http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html ) I think it's okay but I will keep my eye on this as well

Comment: @PhillPafford, interesting -- I didn't know they relaxed the restrictions.  I'd still limit myself to `[A-Za-z0-9_-]` just to maximize compatibility and minimize confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance issue is in your `showCarinfo` function. You're preforming DOM selection in a loop.

Don't do that. Instead cache the selection...

```
function showCarinfo() {
    var cars = $("input[name*=car_id]");
    for ( var car_number = 0; car_number < cars.length; car_number++ ) {
        cars.eq(i); // do stuff
    }
}
```

---

or you can use `.each()`

```
function showCarinfo() {
    $("input[name*=car_id]").each(function() {
        // do stuff
    });
}
```

---

Also, if the only thing the handler is doing is calling that function, a small optimization would be to do this...

```
$("input[name*=car_id]").change(showCarinfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a guess, but I would try binding the `change` event to all `input` elements and filtering them when the event is called:

```
$("input").change(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('name').indexOf('car_id') == 0) {
    showCarinfo();
  }
});
```

That way jQuery doesn't have to block page execution to attach event handlers to the elements based on selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$('input[name$="[car_id]"]').change(function(){
  // codes
});
```